# compose update not working if using php8 (xxx in the lock file but not in remote repositories ,...)

Tags: composer-php, magento2, php-8

I've a composer project (magento 2, upgraded from php7 to php 8), if now i use php 8 (inside docker) run "composer udpate", it will shows

Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

```
  Problem 1
    - Root composer.json requires mobiledetect/mobiledetectlib 2.8.39, found mobiledetect/mobiledetectlib[2.8.39] in the lock file but not in remote repositories, mak                 e sure you avoid updating this package to keep the one from the lock file.
  Problem 2
    - Root composer.json requires magento/composer-root-update-plugin 2.0.2 -> satisfiable by magento/composer-root-update-plugin[2.0.2].
    - magento/composer-root-update-plugin 2.0.2 requires composer/composer ^1.0 || ^2.0 -> found composer/composer[2.2.18] in the lock file but not in remote reposito                 ries, make sure you avoid updating this package to keep the one from the lock file.
  Problem 3
    - Root composer.json requires magento/ece-tools ^2002.1.11 -> satisfiable by magento/ece-tools[2002.1.11, 2002.1.12].
    - magento/ece-tools[2002.1.11, ..., 2002.1.12] require colinmollenhour/credis ^1.6.0 -> found colinmollenhour/credis[v1.13.0] in the lock file but not in remote r                 epositories, make sure you avoid updating this package to keep the one from the lock file.
  Problem 4
    - Root composer.json requires magento/magento-cloud-metapackage >=2.4.5 <2.4.6 -> satisfiable by magento/magento-cloud-metapackage[2.4.5].
    - magento/magento-cloud-metapackage 2.4.5 requires fastly/magento2 ^1.2.34 -> found fastly/magento2[1.2.187] in the lock file but not in remote repositories, make                  sure you avoid updating this package to keep the one from the lock file.
```

But it will work fine in php7.4(inside docker), do anyone know what's the problem?

More info:
docker info

```
php72:
    container_name: web_php
    image: webmaketech/php74
    build: ./php72
    volumes:
      - ./src:/var/www
      - ./php72/php.ini:/usr/local/etc/php/php.ini
      - ./php72/php-fpm.conf:/usr/local/etc/php-fpm.d/www.conf
php810:
    container_name: web_php_810
    image: webmaketech/php810
    build: ./php810
    volumes:
      - ./src:/var/www
      - ./php810/php.ini:/usr/local/etc/php/php.ini
      - ./php810/php-fpm.conf:/usr/local/etc/php-fpm.d/www.conf
```

Comment: Could https://community.magento.com/t5/Magento-2-x-Technical-Issues/Magento-2-4-4-EE-composer-update-issue/td-p/496475 help?

Comment: Please share more details. How did you configure the Docker containers? Are they running the exactly same configuration, besides one using PHP 7.4 and the other using PHP 8?

Comment: i build my own image and container, push to docker repo

Answer (score 0):

You can ignore platform requirements. run the below command.

```
composer udpate --ignore-platform-reqs
```

Comment: not work, the errors are same

Comment: can you please check your composer Version

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it. `--ignore-platform-reqs` ignores **platform** requirements, not dependencies on other packages

Comment: the composer version is 2.2.18, actually this is the magento cloud project, i upgraded it from magento 2.4.3 to 2.4.5

Comment: remarks: php7 + composer 2.2.8 it works fine

Answer (score -1):

searched 2 days on internet, finally got solution

```
composer config -g repo.packagist composer https://mirrors.aliyun.com/composer
```

after run this command, i can process now

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it. Why do you need to use a mirror after all?

Comment: Honestly , i'm not quite understand.